# MySQL JOIN, only get max value

Tags: mysql, join, timestamp

I'm struggling with the following situation:

I have a users table with authors of plugins in it. I have a plugins table with plugins in it (name and id). I also have a version table. This version table holds all the versions of a plugin released, for example 1.0, 1.1 etcetera.Now the version records also holds mcversions, which is a version of the engine that the plugin is made for.

Here is the query I made:

```
SELECT
`plugins`.`name`,
users.username,
versions.version,
mcversions.version
FROM
users
INNER JOIN `plugins` ON `plugins`.author = users.id
INNER JOIN versions ON versions.id = `plugins`.id AND versions.time
INNER JOIN mcversions ON versions.mcversion = mcversions.id
```

Now there is one problem: I only want to get the version and the mcversion that belongs to the version where the versions.time is the highest (it's a timestamp).
So I want a list of plugins with the name, the author, the latest version and the mcversion that the latest version is made for.

I anyone could help me, I would be very happy!

~Bas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
`plugins`.`name`,
users.username,
maxvers.version,
mcversions.version
FROM
users
INNER JOIN `plugins` ON `plugins`.author = users.id

INNER JOIN (SELECT version, MAX(time), id FROM versions) AS maxvers  ON maxvers.id = `plugins`.id 

INNER JOIN mcversions ON versions.mcversion = mcversions.id
```

I havn't tested this, but if you use that subquery to find the max row (as you normally would), draw only from that subquery instead of the entire versions table to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get the following error:
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM versions) AS maxvers  ON maxvers.id = `plugins`.id

Comment: I had an extra ) on `SELECT version, MAX(time), id) <--- `. Not sure if that fixes it. Change to `, MAX(time), id FROM`

Comment: Try some debugging steps (if you're still on this issue). Try parts of it on their own; for instance make sure that `SELECT version, MAX(time), id FROM versions` returns the proper things, etc. The logic is right, the syntax/execution might be wrong. (Again, I don't have the means to test it myself as of now)